# Can an enclosed Pelton Turbine be used as a pump?

Tags: mechanical, fluid-pump

Can an enclosed Pelton Turbine be used as a pump, perhaps through the centrifugal forces created in a enclosed Pelton Turbine when it rotates at speed?

The water striking out of the buckets of a Pelton turbine is left with diminished energy but because the wheel is rotating continuously at high speeds due to very high velocity water jet then, is there any possibility of development of centrifugal forces that may lift up the water through a discharge pipe connected to the casing of the turbine which actually happens in centrifugal pumps?

Is there any possibility of this, even if this happens to a small degree? Can create centrifugal forces lift the water, so it functions as pump and turbine simultaneously?

Please suggest any means by which we could pump the discharged water via a pelton turbine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about physics

Answer (score 1):

A small consideration of energy tells you this is nonsensical: you're extracting energy with the turbine, and a pump is a device which uses energy to do work on the water, so increasing the height at which the water exits the turbine will only decrease the output of the turbine.